# Android Video View not playing the recorded video uploaded to service through url

Tags: android

```
 This is my code please tell  where am i doing wrong,
    I am receiving the uri from service and i have implemented the following code which is not running the video properly,but some videos are playing great and some gets played only when it is buffered completely
```

The video loaded to service which was already in sdcard are playig without stopping.

But the video which i record and upload to service plays only after getting buffered completely

In worse cases these videos also dosent play at all
pleas tell me where i am going wrong

```
                progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MoviePlayer.this);

                // set a title for the progress bar

                progressDialog.setTitle("Please Wait");

                // set a message for the progress bar

                progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");

                // set the progress bar not cancelable on users' touch

                progressDialog.setCancelable(false);

                // show the progress bar

                progressDialog.show();

                try {

                    // set the media controller in the VideoView

                    myVideoView.setMediaController(mediaControls);

                    // set the uri of the video to be played
```

This where i get the url in video and try to play it

```
                    myVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(VideoPath));
                    if (ConnectApi.printBool) {
                        System.out.println("VideoPath VideoPath" + VideoPath);
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();

                }

                myVideoView.requestFocus();

                // we also set an setOnPreparedListener in order to know when the video
                // file is ready for playback
        This is where my audio get recorded completely

                myVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

                    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {

                        // close the progress bar and play the video

                        if (progressDialog != null) {
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                            progressDialog = null;
                        }
                        // if we have a position on savedInstanceState, the video
                        // playback should start from here

                        myVideoView.seekTo(position);

                        if (position == 0) {

                            myVideoView.start();

                        } else {

                            // if we come from a resumed activity, video playback will
                            // be paused

                            myVideoView.pause();

                        }

                    }

                });
                myVideoView.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            }
        enter code here

        }
```